# c++ Windows makefile 32k param limit / *.o to *.a files linking

Tags: windows, arm

I'm struggling with following problem.

I'm building mbed_os, which is operating system for embedded MCU's. There is option build bunch of *.o files during compilation, or link it to *.a library and then use it together with my own code.

If I build mbed_os and list all *.o files in my makefile separately, it works well and final binary runs great. But when I create *.a library during compilation and then list it in my makefile, final binary doesn't run on MCU and MCU looks freezed. But compilation is sucessffull. That's my first problem.

So i can temporarily bypass *.a problem by using bunch of *.o files in makefile instead of single *.a file. But there is second thing.

When I use much features from mbed_os, I need of course very much *.o files and at some point I'm getting compilation error like "*arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory*". After some googling I have discovered that there is 32k limit for windows cmd agrument and as I have found out, list of *.o files is slightly bigger than 32k characters.

Is there some way how to fix this?

List of *.o files in my makefile is added to SYS_OBJECT variable like

```
SYS_OBJECTS += ./_libs_/mbed-os_ ... AnalogIn.o
SYS_OBJECTS += ./_libs_/mbed-os_ ... BusIn.o
SYS_OBJECTS += ./_libs_/mbed-os_ ... BusInOut.o
SYS_OBJECTS += ./_libs_/mbed-os_ ... BusOut.o
...
```

And I'm using GNU ARM Eclipse build tools stored in

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU ARM Eclipse\Build Tools\2.8-201611221915\bin\make.exe
```

and arm-none-eabi-gcc-6.3.1. My OS is Windows 10 PRO 10.0.14393.

Important thing is that when I compile it with Windows 10 bash, everything works fine, so the problem appears only in Win cmd.

Comment: `After some googling I have discovered that there is 32k limit for windows cmd agrument` Usually compilers give you a way to write the command line to a file and then pass the filename to it. Start there.

Comment: Are you using mbed-cli?

Comment: @Qix - can you help me with more information how to pass params to the file and than give it as an argument to the console? Arm-gcc-noneabi has param named --specs, is that it? I have noticed there is used something like nano.specs so maybe I need to append it to the nano.specs, or use it besides my own separate file.

Comment: @Sean Houlihane - at first we tried it in mbed-cli, it worked fine, but now we have our compile server and need to build it without CLI. So mbed-cli is proof it is possible to bypass that 32k limit, but currently don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Solution how to bypass 32k limit was simple. Thank you for responses, especially to @Qix. Instead of this line in makefile

```
$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SYS_OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS)
```

are arguments saved to file .args.txt and then reference to the file is passed to the linker as an argument

```
$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SYS_OBJECTS)
    @echo $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) > .args.txt
    $(LD) @./.args.txt
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because, on Windows CMD, the output of the `@echo ... > .args.txt` command has a limit on itself of 8192 characters, so only the first 8192 characters are written to the file `.args.txt`